# Web2py - How edit user profile and membership in one view?

Tags: python, web2py

I'm have a custom form to edit (update form) a "auth_user" object, but I need edit in the same form his "auth_membership"

How can I do that?

To a easy way I'd tried to add a reference to auth_membership table in the auth_user table, but the result was: type 'exceptions.KeyError' 'auth_membership'.

There are a clean way to edit a user with this added field(Role)?

I'm have the groups definition in auth_group and user-group relationship in auth_membership.

Thanks in advance.
Christian.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way I found for this is using **SQLFORM** for user form and **SQLFORM.grid** for membership panel. Also I think it would be useful to have a grid to list the users.

So I created a solution which shows **userform** and also **memberships** inside an ajax panel.

Take a look in my coding blog: [manage users and memberships at the same form](http://rochacbruno.com.br/web2py-manage-users-and-membership-in-the-same-form/)